# is it possible to make a sword with all enchantments possible with only books

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

there already was a post similar but i have a question, is it possible to make a Unbreaking 3, Looting 3, Sweeping Edge 3, Sharpness 5, Fire Aspect 2, Knockback 2, Mending with only books and not other swords, i can't find a way  (i once was able to make it but i don't know which order anymore)

Answer (score 0):

There was a version that you could do it but you can't do it in 1.15+

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/301849)

Comment: @KyleRone I'm going to have to disagree with that standing because it attempts to answer the question, but not in a good way. It would do well to add details and/or justification, however it is not in such a way that it should be deleted.

Comment: I actually found the way to do it, so i add looting sweeping edge knockback and fire aspect + a sharpness unbreaking and mending book (i made the books out of only single books) and it costs like 16 levels to mend them together and 35 levels to do it on a sword i tested it. thanks for the help eitherway

Comment: @boymen1980 if what you did solved your problem can you write it as an answer to your question? Self-answering is encouraged if you found a good way to solve your problem.